# windows service throws an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I am a newbie in C# .net and I am trying to get a windows service work. I followed this tutorial

```
http://www.beansoftware.com/NET-Tutorials/Create-Windows-Services.aspx

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

        }


        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
        private void FolderWatcherTest_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\FolderLog.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been created. ");
            writer.Close();
        }

        private void FolderWatcherTest_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\FolderLog.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been deleted. ");
            writer.Close();
        }

        private void FolderWatcherTest_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\FolderLog.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been renamed. ");
            writer.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

I was able to get the sevice registered in the windows service. But when I try to start it, it gives me an error 2: The system cannot find the file specified

I am not sure whats going on. Also I am kinda confused where these methods are being called as the tutorial didnt make any reference to these methods

```
private void FolderWatcherTest_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\FolderLog.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been created. ");
            writer.Close();
        }

        private void FolderWatcherTest_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\FolderLog.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been deleted. ");
            writer.Close();
        }

        private void FolderWatcherTest_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\FolderLog.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been renamed. ");
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE1**

ok I was able to register the service. I was running the .exe to install as a service from a different folder where why project files were. But now it registers fine. However I am not able to fire up these 
private void FolderWatcherTest_* methods. They are supposed to log the changes when I change the file name on the desktop. Any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: I just wrote a Windows Service, and found that adding 'Debugger.Break();' was a godsend. That line will bring up VS so you can debug it.

Comment: @lian:The windows service can be debugged just like the regular program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first make sure that your service can start. Comment out file watcher code temporarily until you able to actualy start the service. Try re installing your windows service with [InstallUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This utility is usually located here (Windows 7):

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe
```

Run this command first, it will uninstall service:

```
installutil /u yourproject.exe
```

The service should disappear from list of registered services. If this does not work you can use [sc delete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742045%28WS.10%29.aspx) command to do the same. After you removed the service, find where you exe is. It is usually located in `\bin\Debug\yourproject.exe` or `\bin\Release\yourproject.exe` folders under your project directory. Run this command to register this exe as windows service:

```
installutil yourproject.exe
```

There should be no errors and it should say "The Commit phase completed successfully."

Look at this [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp).

Comment: @Autolycus: you don't have file watcher instance. Nobody is calling these methods. From your tutorial: Step 6: Open service1.cs in design mode and from Toolbox select FileSystemWatcher control and set its name property to FolderWatcher. Step 7: Go to FileSystemWatcher control’s properties and give the path of folder which needs to be monitered. Or you can set this path in app.config file of your project and specify this app.config path in OnStart event of your service.   http://midnightcubicle.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/creating-windows-service-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

The Onstart method should have some logic to trigger these events which you have subscribed via FileSystemWatcher.

Do you have those txt files in the specified drive/directory first?

Also see eventviewer under control panel for any service errors.

Comment: I do have the files in specified directory. I am not sure what can I do to fire up the events

Comment: Where is the code in which your hooking up the events with the filesystemwatcher component? Plus not just hooking up the event, also look here as a reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you Install a windows services you have a option of running on a

1. local system account
2. Service account

If you are running on the service account you need to give the permission to the service account on that folder.

please check the account on which you are running.

Comment: But does this cause for file not found xception?

Comment: yes this may also cause the problem.If the account does not have the permission to view the file it will give this error.

Comment: I think your right, since onstart method doesnt have any logic for the service to do and plus at start itself its throwing error, i guess the xception is thrown not by events but rather by system for not having permission. Lets see what OP has to say.